# How to run Powershell inside VS Code in Version 2

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Let's pretend we have the following powershell script, that we want to run inside Visual Studio Code:

```
if (!(Get-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ea 0)) {
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}

Get-SPFarm
```

This will result in the following well known error out of the box:

> Get-SPFarm : Microsoft SharePoint is not supported with version
>   4.0.30319.42000 of the Microsoft .Net Runtime.

The usual solutions a la editing the powershell.exe.config did not do the trick for me and I cannot find a fitting config or json file inside the `%Userprofile%\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.PowerShell-0.11.0` folder.

the launch.json looks like a promising approach, since it offers the ability to configure different debug profiles:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "PowerShell",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "PowerShell Launch (current file)",
            "script": "${file}",
            "args": ["-Version 2"],
            "cwd": "${file}"
        },
     /*......*/
    ]
}
```

But the args parameter only calls the script file with the defined arguments, not the powershell.exe.

The problem at hand is: how can we run powershell.exe inside VS Code with different .Net versions?

Relevant links:

- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2017/02/13/debugging-powershell-script-in-visual-studio-code-part-2/